# make lower half of a n*n list zero without using any functions in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, matrix

1. I tried to solve it by using 2 for loops and an if statement . But i was unable to get the desired output.

INPUT-

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

```
thislist=[1]*10
thislist=[thislist]*10
print(thislist)
for i in range(10): 
    for j in range(10): 
        print(thislist[i][j], end = " ") 
    print() 
print()
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        if i>j:
            thislist[i][j]=0
for i in range(10): 
    for j in range(10): 
        print(thislist[i][j], end = " ") 
    print()
```

This was the output i got:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

2. but when i made a list using the below method i got the desired output.

```
thislist=[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
          [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
          [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
          [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
          [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
          [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
          [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
          [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
          [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
          [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
print(thislist)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        if i>j:
            thislist[i][j]=0
for i in range(10): 
    for j in range(10): 
        print(thislist[i][j], end = " ") 
    print()
```

note-This is the desired OUTPUT-

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Can someone explain whats the difference between the above 2 codes?

Comment: what is the input ? what is the desired output ? please make Your queston more clear.

Comment: ok - what is the desired output ? what means 'the lower half of n*n' ?

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, the problem comes from the manner you created your list of list. In your first example, you do something like this:

```
list1 = [1]*10
list_of_list1=[list1]*10
```

`list_of_list1` is actually a list of **shallow** copies of the original `list1`. Then if you modify a value in `list_of_list1`, the modification will occurs in all the rows of `list_of_list1`.

The opposit of a **shallow** copy is a **deep** copy. You might want to search more info on the Internet about this topic

In the mean time, you can simply try this.

```
thislist = []
for row in range(10):
    list1 = [1]*10
    thislist.append(list1)
```

But I usually go with **numpy** when it is available.